# What is the best way to properly set the id for two separate roles after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a job board where I set two separate roles: applicant and company. In the application_controller there's a before action of set_user. When a company creates a company profile using their role they are directed to enter their company information through the form. When saved, the company creator is taken to the dashboard.

On the dashboard there is a company profile button that is to show the details the company entered after the sign up path. When the company profile button is clicked an Action Controller error with the message "Couldn't find Company with 'id'=?"is showing.

The id is not properly set for the company and I'm confused to finding the best way to set an id. There is id, user_id and company_id that I'm seeking to determine what to set and make sense of.

[error message after clicking Company Profile button]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO79S.jpg

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      before_action :set_user
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

      def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
          if resource.role == 'company'
            new_company_path
          else
            companies_path
          end
      end
```

**companies_controller.rb**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_company, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :only => [ :new , :edit, :update, :destroy ] do
    redirect_to companies_path unless current_user && current_user.role == "company"
  end

  def new
    @company = Company.new(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: "Company was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:avatar, :name, :website, :about)
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Company Profile', company_path %>
```

Comment: It is no clear to me what controllers and views cause the error. But when you want to build a link to a company page, then you will need to use a path helper like this: `company_path(company)` with `company` being the company to link to.